# Opencart order custom fields

Tags: php, opencart, custom-fields

In opencart there is a table 'als_order_custom_field'. What is the purpose of this table??

Basically i want to store some additional info with each order but dont know what is the best way to do this. I have done something like this in woocommerce.

Comment: OpenCart version? Is it 2.0? If not then maybe you have installed some extension that created this table and in this case I have no idea. If it's OC 2.0, then this table is prepared for you to create your own custom fields but I hadn't have yet enough time to play with OC 2.0 that deeply.

Comment: Do you have idea about any other way to do this??

Comment: It is best not to use any existing default fields for own purposes. As it is a new install you never know when that field might be required by a feature you do want to use. Rather safe than sorry. The curom_field is used in the cutomer address (from looking at payment_address.php)